# copy image over image in Content body?

Tags: theming

I want to overlay an image over another in the Content body. How do I achieve this? I do not know much about coding or themeing.

Could someone guide me please?

Thanks

Comment: Where are these images coming from? Are they both Image fields? You will probably need to edit the `node.tpl.php` in your theme and add some custom CSS (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474/how-do-i-position-one-image-on-top-of-another-in-html).

Comment: No, they are not image fields, I'm inserting the images in the body field using Wysiwyg editor. Thank you for the Link, I'll try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your own CSS classes to the images via the WYSIWYG editor. The code provided on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474/how-do-i-position-one-image-on-top-of-another-in-html should do what you are looking for:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.image1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.image2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img class="image1" src="https://placehold.it/50" />
  <img class="image2" src="https://placehold.it/100" />
</div>
```